# load() function issue on preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preload

I've an issue with jQuerys `.load()` and would to ask for some help. I'm using load for firing a function after the site is loaded. I'm using a small image-preloading script

```
 function preload(arrayOfImages) {
   $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
     $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
   });
 }


 preload([
    'img/about_1.gif',
    'img/contact_1.png',
    // and much more images 
 ]);
```

and some pictures in the body who don't need to be preloaded.

What I am trying to achieve is, to fire a function after the site has been completely loaded. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function () {
       console.log("all loaded");
       $('#curtain').animate({top: '-=1000px'}, 'slow', 'linear', function() { $(this).remove(); });
       $('#loading').animate({top: '-=1000px'}, 'slow', 'linear', function() { $(this).remove(); });
    });
});
```

unfortunately it does fire before the whole page is loaded. Is there something I have to know about `.load()` and why it does not work?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding the img tags on the body and see if it works

Comment: what exactly do you mean? Put them in a `<div>` and position it `left: 9999;`?

Comment: There are many ways to do that. visibility:hidden, opacity:0, width:0, height:0. But first you need to make sure if what I said works for you.

Comment: okay thanks i will try that and tell you! `display: none;` won't work right? because its not actually in the dom?

Comment: yes display:none wont cause the images to load.

Comment: where are you firing `preload`?

Comment: @SpYk3HH in the `<head>` before the `$(document).ready()`. Should it be in there?

Comment: @supersize, no just inside the `$(document).ready(function() {` which can also be written shorter as `$(function() {` ... anyway, moving it into doc ready might help

Comment: seemed to help! Thanks!